# Ubuntu on Windows 10 with Windows Terminal (preview)

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there any way I can make the Windows 10 Ubuntu terminal app use the new Windows Terminal Preview?

**Ubuntu app:**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

**Windows Terminal Preview:**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701

I have both installed and working, but Ubuntu uses the regular Windows Command Prompt style.

If this isn't possible, is it possible to get an improved terminal for the Windows Ubuntu app at all? For example with tabs and detailed customisation.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click on Settings.

  [image: Screenshot]
- Choose a text editor to edit that .json file.
- Find `profiles` entry and add this after the CMD entry putting a comma (,) after `}` to separate the entries.

  ```
  {
      "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
      "closeOnExit" : true,
      "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
      "commandline" : "ubuntu",
      "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
      "cursorShape" : "bar",
      "fontFace" : "Consolas",
      "fontSize" : 10,
      "guid" : "{GUID}",
      "historySize" : 9001,
      "icon" : "Absolute path of icon",
      "name" : "Ubuntu",
      "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
      "snapOnInput" : true,
      "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
      "useAcrylic" : true
  }
  ```
- Save the file. Click on drop-down menu again to check if it has been added.

  [image: Screenshot 2]

**Notes:**

1. To get the GUID of an app, see this question: [How do I get GUID of apps installed from Microsoft Store?](https://superuser.com/q/1455847/1049284)
2. You can download the logo in png format from anywhere of x48. I've used [this icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/3166/ubuntu-logo_icon) and 48x48 size.

***Credits:*** [My answer](https://superuser.com/a/1456188/1049284) on [How do I add application on Windows Terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/1456187/1049284)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Despite valid JSON I am getting "Failed to reload settings". This dialog is thrown whenever I save the settings file in Sublime Text. However Ubuntu did appear in the menu and it does bring up my Ubuntu instance with the applications I've installed.

I suppose this is just a preview bug of some sort but worth noting as I spent some time trying to resolve the error before realising my updating settings file has been loaded.

Comment: You can also let Windows Terminal generate the file for you. Close the Windows Terminal, rename the profiles,json file to profiles.json.old and open it again.

Comment: I notice Ubuntu won't let me use Ctrl-C/V to copy/paste, I have to use the mouse. Ctrl + Shift-V doesn't work either. I don't see any fields for copy/paste in the new windows terminal settings JSON.

Comment: @SaltyDog  i left GUID and icon path intentionally. Have you given the actual values for them? Can you please paste the settings json on some Pastebin and let me know the link? May be there's some error. Also Ctrl+C is keyboard interrupt which terminates the ongoing process. So it won't act as a shortcut to copy things.

Comment: The GUID was missing brackets, adding them resolved the syntax error. Strange that the config still worked and I could open Ubuntu terminal from the menu. Good point about Ctrl-C. Ctrl-V is what I really need, that keystroke works in new terminal preview app I wonder if I can make it work in the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Mystery solved, looks like there was already an Ubuntu config in there. I had two, the one I added from here didn't show until I fixed the syntax error. The other's GUID is different and the commandline value is `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu`.

Comment: @SaltyDog Wait a minute!! Did I forget `{}` in GUID? Fair call. Also, both command line values work for me. Don't you get Ubuntu after running `ubuntu` in CMD? Which Ubuntu app are you using since there are 3 apps in MS Store. Also, if this answer solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on ✔.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes both command line values work for me. The app is [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: +1 for the link to the Ubuntu icon ;)